# How to use Microsoft Fakes to isolate a web service without using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, web-services, microsoft-fakes, isolation, shim

I am testing a web service client and need to isolate the call to the web service.

I have already been told that we can not use dependency injection.  How can I isolate the webservice so that I can test the business logic that calls that service.  Since I can not control the webservice I need to be sure of the value that the service will return.

I have been told that using Microsoft Fakes I can do this, but do not know how to define the fake.

A simplified version of the code that I am testing is:

```
var client = new Serviceprovider.ServiceProxies.PromoService.PromoServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = client.Open();
Promo promoFromMaps = client.GetPromoById(exitingPm.NetworkId, true, true, true, exitingPm.MapsPromoId);
```

I want to control the values stored in promoFromMaps to be able to test the business logic that occurs after that.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Unit-Test-a-having-404c2a18

Comment: It looks like you'd need to shim the needed members of PromoServiceClient. Something along the lines of `ShimPromoServiceClient.GetPromoByIdInt32BooleanBooleanBooleanInt32 = () => new Promo()`, though you may want to shim something inside instead. I can't really tell what part you need isolated and what part you're testing. I'd also push back a bit, because even if this works, shims are naturally ugly code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should read the following Microsoft documentation on the subject: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

What you need to do is right-click on the Serviceprovider reference and select **Add Fake**. This will create a folder in your test project called Fakes. After that the entire DLL is faked and you can use the faked **PromoService** through the name **ShimPromoService**. You can then set it up something like this:

```
ShimPromoService.PromoServiceClient = () => new Client(); //Probably return a mock or something
```

That way you can return a mock if you want to (using Moq, NSubstitute etc) from the PromoServiceClient method.